# How to clean my jetted tub when commercial cleaners fail?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, hot-tub

The previous owners of our house badly negelegted the jetted tub. We recently corrected a large number of pluming issues with the tub, and are in the process of trying to get the lines to run clean.

I've tried the traditional dish detergent as is suggested, and then I went to harsher chemicals. I've tried multiple bottles of "Oh Yuk" cleaner and some amount of grime comes out, but then, after its drained, black flecks still come out.

I tried "Oh Yuks" harsher treatment, with more chemicals and letting it soak for 24 hours. I even ran the jet on and off for probably a total run time of 2 hours during this time. Still, when I was done and ran the jets, black flecks came out.

Is there a product I can use that will clean this out?

Comment: How hard is your water?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - We don't have a softener, but its really not bad. Not much buildup on shower heads or appliances. Much softer than water in other houses I've lived in.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some horrible garden or jetted tubs growing stuff and that was one of the reasons I got 1 place at 1/4 market value on a short sale. Drain the tub ether purchase several gallons of liquid chlorine or a couple gallons of bleach.

First fill the tub with plain water as full as practical) and run the pump you want to get rid of any cleaning chemical residue drain, you may want to do this 2x if your last treatment is not removed. Fill the tub with water and add 2 full gallons of bleach or chlorine, turn the pump on and the exhaust fan. Let run for 1 hour, let sit for an hour (this allows the strong chlorine to get in the air passages for the bubbles and kill anything in there. Run the pump for another hour or longer. 
Drain the tub and fill with cold water, run the pump for a couple of minutes and drain. Fill again run then drain again.

If this does not clear it up get 1/2 gallon of 25% hydrogen peroxide. Fill the tub with hot water and add the peroxide, the peroxide will increase the heat in the water, run , let sit like before for a few cycles drain and rinse.

I used this method on a home that had a sewer back up into the tub and stuff was growing on the surface yuk. I replaced the broken drain line and over night the tub was like new after polishing the surface. Total cost was approximately 30$ and about 6 hours filling and draining.

Comment: Sounds like this would work, but I may use it as a last resort. From what I have read, using bleach (even in much lower quantities) can eat away at the gaskets inside the pump. May be necessary in some cases though. Hydrogen peroxide is also an oxidizer, so I imagine it would do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried "Oh Yuk" but I do use a Jacuzzi product from Jacuzzi that has worked very well for us. It involves a two-step process that seems to get rid of the gunk in the system. Based on your question it may require several applications. In fact probably any cleaner you use will require multiple applications. Give it a shot. I guess I could have taken a pic of the English side. 
[image]